# Better way to fill lower triangle of a matrix using a vector

Tags: r, matrix

I want to rearrange a returned vector from a function into a lower triangle matrix. As

```
resultF <- function(data){ # for example
  rw  <- nrow(data)
  res <- matrix(0, rw, rw)
  res[lower.tri(res)] <- 1
  return (sort(c(res), decreasing = T))
}
r <- 6
c <- 2
data <- matrix(rnorm(100), r, c)

result <- resultF(data) # function returns 6 * 6 vector with first elements of the vector containing the values of the lower triangle in this case 36 elements returned, and 1-15 are lower triangle values.
```

This gives me what i want, my question is, are there better way of doing this?

```
mat   <- matrix(0, r, r)
mmt   <- mat[lower.tri(mat)] 
size  <- length(mmt)
val   <- result[1:size]
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- val
mat
```

output:

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
[5,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
[6,]    1    1    1    1    1    0
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, i.e., provide a working example of `f` and the expected output. Also, don't forget to use `set.seed` if you create random numbers for an example.

Comment: How about... `mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- result[1:length(matrix(0, r, r)[lower.tri(matrix(0, r, r))])]`... all those four statements executed in a single command... :)

Comment: Please provide an example that makes it obvious, which value goes into which cell. If your matrices are large you should look into the triangular sparse matrix class implemented by package Matrix.